# Mongo populate in optional field giving cast error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a 'vendor' and 'media' collection, media collection store vendor profile images and that is not mandatory field for vendors. Some vendors have profile picture some not, I want to list all vendors including their profile pictures reference. But I'm getting cast error when I populate profilePicture from meidas. I have other populate like 'userId', 'venueId' those are mandatory fields and it works.

**Error:** 
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "xyz" at path "_id" for model "medias" undefined

**Find Query:**

```
const result = await resultObject.skip(skip)
    .populate('userId')
    .populate('venueId')
    .populate('profilePicture')
      .limit(parseInt(obj.pageSize, 10))
      .sort({ [obj.sortColumn]: parseInt(obj.sortValue, 10) });
    return result;
```

**medias model**

```
const MediasModel = () => {
  const MediasSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    url: { type: String, required: true },
    key: { type: String},
  }, { timestamps: { createdAt: 'createdDate', updatedAt: 'modifedDate' } });
  return mongoose.model('medias', MediasSchema);
};

module.exports = MediasModel();
```

**vendors model**

```
const Vendors = new mongoose.Schema({
  venueId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'venues' },
  userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  profilePicture: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'medias' },
}, { timestamps: { createdAt: 'createdDate', updatedAt: 'modifedDate' } });

module.exports = mongoose.model('vendors', Vendors);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
const Vendors = require('path/to/model_vendor');

Vendors.find()
.populate([{path: 'venues'}, {path: 'users'}, {path: 'medias'}])
.skip(skip_value)
.limit(limit_value)
.sort({condition: 1 }) // Modify according to your need
.exec().
.then(vendors=>{
console.log(vendors)
}).catch(err=>{
console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: Tried but not getting none of the populate results, I mean now users, venues are note listing, getting all the vendors without populated fields

Comment: It worked with same populate query, the issue was some old junk data in the database.

Comment: @Dibish yes, you are right. As your error suggest  Cast to ObjectId failed for value "xyz" at path "_id"            xyz cannot be objectid